# Why replace function is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a number say 1,000 and i am going to convert comma into dot and i used the function

```
var x = "1,000";
x.replace(/,/g , ".");
```

So, the number became as 1.000. Now, i used the function below with the converted number

`var x = x.replace(/./g , ",");`

I should return 1,000 but it returns

```
,,,,,
```

I want to know the reason why it is returning like this.

Here is the Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d4N9s/2165/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` is a special character in regex you must escape it `\.` In regex `.` means any character so it is replacing all your characters with a `,`.

Answer (score 0):

`.` means any character in Regular Expression you can use like this

```
var mystring = "1,000"
var mystring = mystring.replace(/,/g , ".");
alert(mystring);
var find=',';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
var mystring = mystring.replace(re, ",");
alert(mystring);
```